# When Input Values To My Program, It Crashes :( C#

Tags: c#

This is the program. Can someone tell me what I did wrong? Every time I input a value for the string SolvingFor, the program crashes. I'm new to coding so if I made a stupid mistake please tell me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PercentageCalculator
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string SolvingFor;
        int part;
        int whole;
        int percent;
        Console.WriteLine("please only use numbers and lowercase letters.");
        Console.WriteLine("Are you trying to solve for percent, part, or           whole?");
         SolvingFor = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());

        if (SolvingFor == "part") {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the Whole");
            whole = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the Percent");
            percent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); ;
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is" + (whole * percent) / 100); }

       else if (SolvingFor == "whole")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the part");
            part = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the Percent");
            percent = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); ;
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is" + (part * 100) / percent);
        }


        else if (SolvingFor == "percent")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the part");
            part = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Value of the whole");
            whole = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); ;
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer is" + (part * 100) / whole);
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please only input valid lowercase letters and numbers. ");
        };
        Console.Read();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception and on what line does it happen? Always include the error information. They aren’t just for fun, they tell you what went wrong and often also why.

Comment: Instead of using `Convert.ToInt32()` to parse user input to get an int. You should use the `int.TryParse()`. Avoid exceptions when you can expect one. _(never trust userinput)_

Comment: That seemed to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Issue:**
Below line from your code is reading just one character.

Instead of `Console.Read()`, use `Console.ReadLine()` to enable you to input multiple characters.

```
 SolvingFor = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());
```

**Second Issue:**
You are using `Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());`

Please note that `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception in anything apart from number is provided as input.

Better use `int.TryParse` which returns if the conversion is successful or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
        //SolvingFor = Convert.ToString(Console.Read());
        SolvingFor = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

if you put(hover) the mouse over ReadLine

[image]

you will see that it returns a string so **Convert.ToString** is not needed

```
        SolvingFor = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The `Convert.ToString()` isn't needed.

Comment: @J.vanLangen yes